# Let $(a_0,a_1,\dotsc)$ be an infinite sequence of natural numbers such that $a_x\equiv a_y\pmod{m}$ iff $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$. Prove that $a_n=n$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $(a_0,a_1,\dotsc)$ be an infinite sequence of natural numbers containing all the natural numbers. Assume that $a_x\equiv a_y\pmod{m}$ if and only if $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$. Prove that $a_n=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I have tried to prove using induction, but I cannot seem to be able to proove the base case $a_0=0$.

Comment: It would seem that for any constant $C$, $a_n = n + C$ is a solution, and if so you of course can't prove $a_n = n$. Is that perhaps what you meant?

Comment: @RonniePavlov It was assumed that $n\mapsto a_n$ is a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. The conclusion $a_n=n$ is correct, see my response below.

Comment: Yup, just missed that statement. Thanks! (I was also, as ever, a little confused by the natural numbers containing $0$ haha.)

Comment: @RonniePavlov I only learned recently that a good part of the world does not consider zero a natural number. What is worse, historically zero was not a natural number (so I cannot argue on historical grounds). So now if I use the notation $\mathbb{N}$ in a paper, I feel explaining in the notations section that $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$.

Comment: This user Jogn altogether asked two questions at MO without any context within two days which both very much look like typical math contest problems. I think we should refrain from helping people cheat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a_x=a_y$, then $a_x\equiv a_y\pmod{m}$ for all positive integers $m$, hence $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$ for all positive integers, so that $x=y$. Therefore $n\mapsto a_n$ is a permutation of the natural numbers. Now the positive integer $m:=|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ satisfies $a_{n+1}\equiv a_n\pmod{m}$, whence $n+1\equiv n\pmod{m}$, and therefore $m=1$. This means that $a_{n+1}$ equals $a_n-1$ or $a_n+1$. However, $a_{n+1}=a_n-1$ would force $a_{n+2}=a_n-2$, $a_{n+3}=a_n-3$, etc., which is a contradiction after $a_n$ steps. Hence $a_{n+1}=a_n+1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and from here it is clear that $a_n=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! 
We know that $n+1\equiv n$ (mod 1), so $a_{n+1} \equiv a_n}$ (mod 1).  From there how would we get to $|a_{n+1}−a_n|$ dividing $(n+1)-n$ ?

Comment: @Jogn I have reformulated the relevant part. Hopefully it is easier to follow now.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to establish $a_0 = 0$.

Comment: @user3840170: Yes, it does. The only increasing permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ is the identity map.